# Fix null is not an object (evaluating 'user.token') react native

Tags: react-native, react-context

I have a screen(LandScreen) where I want the user name and role to show when I login, which worked by when I logout and go to LandScreen I get this error `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'user.token')]`

```
const LandScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${user.token}`;
    axios.get(userInfo)
      .then(response => {
        setPeople(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })

  }, []);


return(
      <View>
           <Text>{people?.name}</Text>
            <Text>{people?.role}</Text>
    <View>
)
}
```

Hope to get an answer, thanks for you help.

Comment: where is your `user` come from ? Can you show full code ?

Comment: ```user``` is unkown.

You need to pass user to the component or get the variabel by useSelector.

Change ```user.token``` -> ```user?.token``` will fix the crash but won't work